# Query Entity by Regex Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to run a query in Google App Engine using Firestore in Datastore mode. What I want to accomplish is to query a string based on a regex. For example, I want a query that would return all entities that match a regex. I could not find anything about regex in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries). I'm looking for something that would look like the following code.

```golang
query := datastore.NewQuery(kind).
    Filter("date =", myRegex)
//then run the query and so forth
```

Thanks for any help!

---

**Edit:**
The regex I want to implement looks like the following `"1/\d\d/2020"

Comment: Regexp filters are not supported.  The best option is to filter on a literal prefix of the regexp (if any) and filter by regexp in the application code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, is there any workarounds?

Comment: @CeriseLimón, I updated my question to describe my regex. How would I implement what you are describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query.  A regexp is not needed.

```
query := datastore.NewQuery(kind).
    Filter("date >=", "1/00/2020").
    Filter("date <=", "1/99/2020").
```